# NPM Dependency upgrade management

Tags: node.js, npm

we wanted to keep two version of package.json

1. Package.json that has the exact version number This version we will use for my upcoming release, primarily to avoid any breaking change in the external code.
2. The second version of package.json we wanted to use the latest versions of all dependencies. We would use a separate nightly build to keep using this version of package.json to run all test. This help us plan our upgrades on dependencies, for the next release.

we can't have 2 files with same name in a folder so we name one of them package.json.star and the nightly job renames it to package.json and uses it to run the tests on the latest versions of dependencies.

Is there a better way to do this. Ideally we would not want the nightly job to delete and rename files. Is there a way to specify something like "npm install --file package2.json" to tell npm install to use a specific file instead of the default package.json.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to specify the `package.json` file you use, since it looks like the code hard codes `package.json`.  There's [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html) but that's a bit different...  I think you're script might be your best bet for this at this time...